# Как оптимзировать изображения PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel, qpixmap

Библиотека *PyQt5* позволяет вставлять изображения через виджет `QLabel`. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
Image = QtWidgets.QLabel(window)                   # Создаём объект QLabel
Image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 100, 100))  # Конфигурация объекта (x, y, width, height)
Image.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('image.png'))        # Присваиваем объекту QLabel Изобржаение
Image.setScaledContents(True)  # Данный метод растягивает изображение на весь объект
```

Такой метод очень прост, но при этом, как оказалось, он тратит огромное количество оперативной памяти. 
Дело в том, что я работаю с достаточно большими изображениями (до 5000 на 5000 точек). Из-за этого программа использует 90 Мб ОЗУ вместо 25 (без использования картинок).

Есть ли какие-нибудь способы сделать так, чтобы поместить большие изображения в `QLabel`, при этом не затратив много ОЗУ? 
Думаю, может помочь *Pillow*, но не знаю как его использовать...

Вот рабочий пример:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(350, 250)
        self.Image = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.Image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 100, 100))
        self.Image.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("image.png"))
        self.Image.setScaledContents(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 90 Мб ОЗУ это, во-первых, очень мало, а во-вторых, примерно столько и должно быть (по 3 байта на пиксель)

Comment: Нет, это асболютно ненормально, когда 3 изображения жрут ОЗУ больше, чем вся программа без них.  Может можно использовать тот же Pillow для сжатия картинок?

И, кстати, забыл упомянуть, что общий вес этих 3-х изображений меньше 3 Мб, а в ОЗУ они занимают 35 Мб. В чём причина этого, я не понимаю. Но проблема явно в изображениях

Comment: Нет, это абсолютно нормально, Pillow тоже использует по 3 байта на пиксель и будет использовать ровно столько же памяти. Причина в том, что сжатые файлы изображений распаковываются, чтобы с ними было возможно работать.

Comment: Может всё-таки есть способы как-то уменьшить потребляемое количество памяти? С такими темпами, скоро моя небольшая программа будет использовать столько же ОЗУ, сколько и браузер...

Comment: А что мешает просто заранее уменьшить размер изображения? Меньше пикселей — меньше памяти

Comment: Эти изображения нельзя ни уменьшить, ни изменить их расширение из-за особенностей работы программы

Comment: В таком случае вам придётся смириться с тем, что в какой-то момент времени они будут жрать много памяти. Вы можете уменьшить размер изображения на лету (всё-таки не поленитесь запустить пример кода от S.Nick), но в момент между чтением большой картинки и её уменьшением всё равно будет жраться память.

Comment: Я уже давно попробовал этот метод, и он ничем мне не помог, к сожалению

Comment: Да, этот способ действительно работает, но этот  же способ описан и у меня `self.Image.setScaledContents(True)` и `scaled(145, 100)` делают одно и то же. Очень жаль, нет никакого способа сжать эти изображения уже при отрисовке

Comment: GreenPy, я вам еще раз попробую сказать - УДАЛИТЕ `self.Image.setScaledContents(True)`

Comment: Это никак не помогло, ещё раз попробую вам сказать...

 Я убрал `self.Image.setScaledContents(True)` и ничего не изменилось!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(350, 250)
        self.Image = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.Image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 145, 100))
 
        self.Image.setPixmap(
            QtGui.QPixmap(
                "photo-1493976040374-85c8e12f0c0e.jpg"
            ).scaled(145, 100))                                  # + scaled(145, 100)
            
# -        self.Image.setScaledContents(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**photo-1493976040374-85c8e12f0c0e.jpg**

**`Ваше изображение слишком велико`** для загрузки (более 2 МБ).

**photo-1493976040374-85c8e12f0c0e.jpg**  --> **`7360`**x**`4912`**  -->

---

**Update**

Вот результат работы вашего приложения с моим изображением.

Что значит не помогло? Посмотрите на результат и объясните лучше что не помогло, какие у вас результаты?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(350, 250)
        self.Image = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.Image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 145, 100))
 
        self.Image.setPixmap(
            QtGui.QPixmap(
                "photo-1493976040374-85c8e12f0c0e.jpg"
            ))                                          # - scaled(145, 100)
            
        self.Image.setScaledContents(True)              # +


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению, это не помогло. Может, всё-таки, есть способ как-то сжать изображения? Они в формате png (сменить формат изображения нельзя из-за особенностей работы программы). Опять же, может вы знаете, как использовать Pillow в PyQt widgets?

Comment: @GreenPy я добавил дополнение в свой ответ, прокомментируйте пожалуйста.

Comment: В моём примере уже есть `setScaledContents(True)` , и это по сути то же самое, как я понимаю. Есть ли ещё способы вставить картинку в QLabel?

Comment: @GreenPy, нет, вы не правильно понимаете. Вы даже не попробовали мой пример, я сожалею. The End.

Comment: Прошу прощения, этот метод действительно работает. Так вышло, что в моём коде присваивание изображения происходит дважды, один из я них изменил, про второй забыл вообще. Ещё раз извиняюсь за эту неувязочку....

Comment: @GreenPy, если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour